# WinRT - caching StorageFolder picked by user

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

Is it safe to cache StorageFolder (or more generally anything that derives from IStorageItem) picked by user (with folder picker)? I need to create some kind of tree of StorageFolders - so users can navigate to picked folder subfolders (and then navigate back). My idea is to store it in:

```
Dictionary<string, StorageFolder> folderPathToParentMap;
```

I wouldn't need it after application restarted - but the question is can I be sure that "access" to `StorageFolder` won't be lost (i.e on suspended ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not trying the following (Courtesy msdn) if you are worried about losing the access during the application session.

```
// Process picked folder
if (folder != null)
{
    // Store folder for future access
    folderToken = Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(folder);
}
else
{
    // The user didn't pick a folder
}
```

Comment: Yes, the AccessCache is made for exactly this purpose. I wrote about this recently on the Building Apps for Windows Blog: http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/buildingapps/archive/2014/06/20/common-questions-and-answers-about-files-and-app-data-part-2-files.aspx